# Understanding AND IF .. = 0 in SQL

Tags: sql

I'm running a script in SQL and am trying to walk through the logic. This is the general structure:

```
SELECT
...
FROM
...
WHERE
...
AND IF (order belongs to x,y,z, 1, IF (order was booked before this data, 1,0)) = 0
```

In the last line for AND IF...what does = 0 imply?

Comment: Put a full line of code, or else we can't determine what you're asking.

Comment: IF is not standard SQL -- what platform are you using?

Comment: what sql dialect is this?

Comment: if it this is mysql, then `if()` is a valid function, and can return the appropriate true/false value: `select if(false, 3, 4) = 4` will return `1`, because the if() evalues to `4`, and `4=4` evaluates to `true`.

Comment: This is some kind of DBMS specific SQL. So what are you using?

Comment: Sorry - my company has its own specific sql language, I wanted to walk through the logic but didn't want to paste the entire script and confuse everyone. Matt retranslating the code into an alternative form made a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It implies the false value of the nested if statement is the desired results for the query

`IF (order belongs to x,y,z`, - If true the value will be `1`, if false then the nested if statement is evaluated.

```
 IF (order was booked before this data
```

, - If this is true then the value will be `1`. If it is is false the value will be `0`.

finally the outcomes of the IF statements are evaluated to see if they are `= 0`.

Basically it is saying if the order belongs to x, y, z then don't include the records.  Also if the order was booked before this date don't include the records.

To represent the logic in a more standard way.

```
SELECT *
FROM
   TableName
WHERE
  Order NOT IN (x,y,z)
  AND OrderDate >= somedate
```